# A plastic tube in my dishwasher which I believe is used to send water to the top rack, flung out during a cycle, melted, now the bottom rack is stuck

Tags: dishwasher, heat, stuck

I tried removing it till I realized, it melted a line through it, is now stuck on the heating element, and the way where I would pull it out cooled off and reformed so i can’t pull it out.

Comment: Photo please, and whats the question.

Answer (score 6):

In the absence of a photo, it sounds like you're going to have to unload the rack in place (not hard if you take the top one right out) to gain access, then use a hacksaw (or hacksaw blade in a handle/wrapped in duct tape) to cut the plastic enough to get the bottom rack out.

Be very careful not to cut into the element at all, in case it can be saved. Unplug, turn off at the wall, or equivalent, just in case.

Then you'll need to get all the old plastic off the element. With sufficient access you might be able to split the melted part and have it come off cleanly. Softening with a heat gun should allow scraping it off.

If you can't get every last bit of plastic off, you'll need a new element as well as a replacement pipe. Also check if you need to replace any clips that held the pipe in place - there must be some reason it came off.